# How to add a legend to a scatter graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scatter-plot, plt

I have plotted a scatter graph that takes two columns from a table using:

```
df.plot.scatter("volume/mm^3", "Cost per m^3/$") 
plt.title("Volume vs. Cost Analysis", size = 16)
plt.ylim((0,80000))
plt.xlim((7500,30000))
```

I am now trying to either annotate each point or create a legend using the first column
How would I do so?

Comment: Read up on `matplotlib.pyplot.annotate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `label` parameter

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 2), columns=['x', 'y'])

df.plot.scatter('x', 'y', label='x')
```

[image]